# asp.net and chrome/safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I am setting up a login form using asp.net 4.0 and having issues with chrome / safari.  The form has an action in javascript to submit data to a dll which IE and firefox execute as intended, but safari downloads the dll and chrome just stops at the execution of the dll.  Not sure if there is a specific way to handle dll's in safari/chrome, but any help you can give would be appreciated.  Below is a code snippet of the js and form.

```
function logIn() {
        // This should be same as, action in form authn scheme
        document.forms[0].action = "/access/oblix/apps/webgate/bin/webgate.dll?/prv/agr/confagr.aspx";
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" runat="server" visible="True" method="post">

<input type="submit" onclick="logIn()" value="Submit" name="submit" style="padding: 2px; margin: 2px" />
```

The site is hosted on IIS 7.5.

Comment: <input type="submit" onclick="logIn()" value="Submit" name="submit" style="padding: 2px; margin: 2px" />

Comment: <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" runat="server" visible="True" method="post">

Comment: Above are the form tags for the actual form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your server-side code to send the correct `Content-Type` header.  (probably `text/html`)

Comment: what do you mean by this?  at the server change this or in the web code add the content-type?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried putting the complete address?

```
document.forms[0].action = "http://mysite.com/access/oblix/apps/webgate/bin/webgate.dll?/prv/agr/confagr.aspx";
```

also are you running this straight from IIS or are you trying it by debugging in visual studio? reason I ask is cause Chrome is weird about this stuff when its not a site loaded in a domain..sorry not sure exactly how to explain that but anyways keep us posted.

Comment: I am running it on iis to make sure get the functionality since the dll is actually an isapi control on the box.

Comment: and using the full address does not work either.  Chrome will go to the dll in the browswer but never executes it

Comment: have you tried adding ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" in your form tag? so it would be:  <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" runat="server" visible="True" method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">

Comment: I tried the enctype in the form tag and it breaks the form and it does not process at all.

Comment: any particular reason why you would runat="server" on your form? it doesn't go to server at all..don't think that's it but just asking